# Explicit css file is not working

Tags: css, html

i dont see that my web page is changing according to the style defined in the css file. when i added the same in html file, it is working. can someone please help. dont know what is wrong.

below is my simple html file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>css</title>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
test
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

below is my css file.

```
<style>
body
{
background-color:lightblue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change css file as: Remove `<style> </style>`

```
body
{
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

Also correct the format of html as

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>css</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
   test
  </body>
</html>
```

This works for Me. Make sure your html and css both the files should be in same folder.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
    body {
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
</style>
```

is not a right way to write a `.css` file.

Remove those style tags from your `.css` file and check again.

Also,

Make sure your `.html` and `.css` files are on the same path
(In order to make things work without changing the `link` tag in your `html` `head`

Just noticed:

Your `body` tag is INSIDE your `head` tag. Which is incorrect.

Right way to do so is,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>css</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped the head tag around everything. And a link tag should always be placed between head tags and not in the body tag.

your code should be like the example below. All the rest seems fine.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>css</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

test

</body>
</html>
```

Css should be like this:

```
body {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**always css link in head section, u can also see the path of the file, Do not use type attributes for style sheets (unless not using CSS),Specifying type attributes in these contexts is not necessary as HTML5 implies text/css and text/javascript as defaults. This can be safely done even for older browsers
type="text/css"**

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
      <body>
         hello
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not necessary if the style.css is in the same folder as the html file

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

HTML-

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>css</title>  
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
</head>  
<body>  
    test  
</body>  
</html>
```

CSS-

```
body {  
    background-color: lightblue;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong CSS syntax. In a CSS file, there are no `<style></style>` tags, they are just rules. So you should have:

```
body
{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Also, you should `link` your CSS file into the `<head>` tag, it is better for your file's organization.